# Which characters will break a double click highlight

Tags: url, character, double-click

I am creating an online picture storage system that renames images using a 7 character alphanumeric code.  These codes are then used in URLs.  I would like to be able to double-click on these codes and copy them from a URL within Chrome's URL bar.  I am finding that certain characters  (`-` and `~`, to name a few) cause double-click to only highlight part of the code.

Is there a list of characters that double-click will not include in its grouping?

Is this an OS or browser specific list?

I would like for my system to use the greatest variety of (URL safe) characters, while still allowing double click to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely browser specific. In IE, `_` is "unsafe", while `-` is "safe". In Chrome, `_` is "safe", `-` is "unsafe". In firefox both are "unsafe". I don't think browsers have any documentation on this. For open-source browsers you can look at the source to see which are safe. I'd only use alphanumeric characters to be sure.